# If true, execute the rest of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a jQuery file, some of which determines the layout and some of which determines events to be clicked later.

The code that determines the layout, I can't put in a CSS file because it's dependent on the `.width()` of some elements — so I'm stuck with JS for now.

What's the best way to make sure these layout changes happen first, and if so, run the rest of the file? Here is an example of the code which determines the layout:

```
    archive.css({left: archivePosition});
    films.css({right: - filmsPosition});
    index.css({left: (nw / 2) - (iw / 2) });
```

And is it worth me separating these into two different JS files?

Comment: So what is the `if` condition you need to evaluate? Why can't you achieve what you need by using media queries in CSS?

Comment: For example, if the above code has been executed, run the rest of the script. (so CSS positions have been set). And I'm dependent on .width()

Comment: Because he's dependent on `width()` he says in the OP. @BenM

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `if the code has been executed`? Unless it's already in some kind of conditional loop, it'll always be executed?

Comment: write your jquery code in a function and call that function right after.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/6xSC5/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#test").width(function(index, width){
        if(width)
        {
            //your conditional code.
        }
    });
});
```